# In Dart Flutter, if else conditions causing problems

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-test, dart-html

In Dart  Flutter if else conditions causing problems.
In this method with if else conditions the forEach loop is not working properly
as it does not  allowing the print statement to print each key and value in the map.

Data for map comes from the firestore database

But
when I remove if else conditions , then it is working properly
Please help.

CODE

```
Future<List<ReviewModel>> getCakeReview(String cakeId) async {
    CollectionReference snap = types.doc(cakeId).collection('Reviews');

    List<ReviewModel> list = [];
    ReviewModel model = ReviewModel("", "", 0, "");
    String userName = "";
    String userDP = "";
    String review = "";
    int rating = 0;
    await snap.get().then((value) {
      for (var result in value.docs) {
        Map<String, dynamic> map = result.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        print(map);

        int i = 0;

        map.forEach((key, value) {
          print(key.toString() + ":" + value.toString());
          print(i++);
          
          if (key.toString() == 'userName') {
            userName = value.toString();
          } else if (key.toString() == 'userDP') {
            userDP = value.toString();
          } else if (key.toString() == 'rating') {
            rating = value;
          } else {
            review = value.toString();
          }
        });

        model = ReviewModel(userName, userDP, rating, review);
        list.add(model);
      }
    });

    print("FS");
    return list;
  }
```

[Output Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8svl.png)

Comment: Can you include `map` data

Comment: map data comes from firestore database from firebase. I have also added  the code and output in console as a image

Comment: what is the output of print(map)?

Comment: It prints  all contents in the map. I have included the image link of code and output

Comment: Ahh, the wonderful "for-switch" antipattern often referenced in thedailywtf.com

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
    map.forEach((key, value) {
      print(key.toString() + ":" + value.toString());
      print(i++);
      
      if (key.toString() == 'userName') {
        userName = value.toString();
      } else if (key.toString() == 'userDP') {
        userDP = value.toString();
      } else if (key.toString() == 'rating') {
        rating = value;
      } else {
        review = value.toString();
      }
    });
```

with

```
userName = map['userName'];
userDP = map['userDP'];
rating = map['rating'];
review = map['review'];
```

to eliminate the "for-switch" anti-pattern.

Comment: Sir thanku for the help, i understand that, what you showed was the right way to do it. But can u please explain why the print statement in my code didn't work 4 times. It is supposed work right. I really want to know why that happens can u please help

Answer (score 0):

Now I got what was the problem,

I try to store  the value(which is not integer when returned from firebase I think) into the rating variable which is an  integer type

so what I did is,
parsed the value to integer and it worked fine.

Code

```
    map.forEach((key, value) {
      print(key.toString() + ":" + value.toString());
      print(i++);
      
      if (key.toString() == 'userName') {
        userName = value.toString();
      } else if (key.toString() == 'userDP') {
        userDP = value.toString();
      } else if (key.toString() == 'rating') {
        rating =int.parse(value);
      } else {
        review = value.toString();
      }
    });
```